# Running Asp.Net 4.6.1 applications in Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I cannot find a definitive answer on this but is it possible to run an Asp.Net Core (2.0) application as .Net 4.6.1 full-framework in order to reference a library that has not been ported yet (In this particular case Spire.Office although I am not sure that detail is relevant)?  I have updated all my csproj files to `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>` and that works great locally.  As soon as I deploy to our IIS server the problems start.  I get the following white error page

[image: Error Page 502.5]

I checked the event viewer and this is what I find:

```
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/XXX' with physical root 
'C:\xxx\xxx\' failed to start process with commandline 
'"C:\xxx\xxx\xxx.exe" ', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : ff.
```

I also see another information event in our viewer as follows

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: xxx.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: a7384df0
P4: mscorlib
P5: 4.6.1590.0
P6: 5787ee1b
P7: 8f6
P8: 2b
P9: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatch
P10:
```

We have other Asp.Net core applications on this box that are running without issue.  Our dev ops guy has us deploying with a bundled runtime per our csproj

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

Any ideas or things I could look at?

Comment: You may have run across this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot#app-startup-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the fix.  The issue was due to swagger/swashbuckle not core/4.6.1/iis.  The xml documentation file generated when opted into was not part of my deployment package.  The error was not revealed until running the exe manually on the command line.  Hope this helps someone.